# Can I restrict poll SCM job to be run only once in a day?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have a poll SCM job , which polls every 5 minutes for a change in Perforce. But I need the job to be triggered only when first edit happens for the files in perforce in a day. Can I restrict poll SCM job to be run only once in a day?

Comment: Do you require that the polling be every 5 minutes or would it be sufficient if the first job of the day were detected with a granularity of 1 hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins itself does not provide this kind of behaviour ("run only for the very first change every day").

You need to split this down into two parts; the first one polling SCM, the second taking care that the job will not run more than once per day.

Possible solution:

- Keep your current polling job, checking for changes every 5 minutes
- add a build step that will disable the job after running (thus preventing a second run on this day)
- create another job that (re-)enables the polling job every morning at 0:00, so the polling job can run upon the next change

If you don't like to see the polling job going into "disabled" state, then you could also remove the job's SCM polling from the job configuration at the end of the run, and have the second job re-establish that. This is a bit more complicated as you need to modify the job configuration.

In any case, "change" will always refer to the last run of the polling job. So if there's two changes A and B on day 1, then the polling job will run once for "A" on day 1, and then immediately again for "B" on day 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark `Poll SCM` instead of `Build Periodically`.

In `Poll SCM` you can write a cron-like entry how often your polling should run, e.g. for once a day (run at 1:00am):

```
0 1 * * *
```

Comment: Technically your cron syntax would run the job only once in day at 1 am , provided there are commits already. what if first commit happens after 1 am ? then we would miss the logic right ? agree ?

Comment: Yes, but that will happen always, you can't know if there is a commit untill you check for it, and the poster wants to do polling only once a day, so he has to decide at what time, usually it is best to use a night in ones timezone.

Comment: yup , if he is limiting himself to run the job only once a day , then he need to make sure that first commits fall in line with the poll scm cron. or if wants to trigger the job as many times a commit happens provided the jenkins job should execute the shell/code only in its first run in a day.

Comment: The poster does not want to poll once a day -- he wants to _run_ the job once a day only. Meaning: poll for change every 5 mins -- run upon first change -- do not run again for that day.

Comment: He wants : `Can I restrict poll SCM job to be run only once in a day ?`

Comment: AlexO is correct. @krzyk  I have a cron script to poll scm in the job as H/5 * * * * , which will make the job to poll scm every 5 minutes. 
I want it in the same way I can't set a time to poll. But I need to Run that job only once (ie; with first change in perforce). Even if I have change in another 5 minutes I don't want to run the job. OR in other way, I have cron  statement to poll SCM in every 5 minutes. But I want to atop polling after a build is triggered in a day. And want to re poll in the next day .

Comment: Hi everyone, while entering ```0 1 * * *``` getting warning ```Spread load evenly by using ‘H 1 * * *’ rather than ‘0 1 * * *’```. Are both the same or have different impact?  ```0 1 * * *``` seems working what I want for, should I just Ignore the warning?