# How to exit Jenkins job if SCM polling does not detect any changes?

Tags: jenkins

Windows Server 2016, Jenkins 2.107.1.  We have GitHub repositories, Git repositories not in GitHub, and CVS repositories.  This link...[Can I restrict poll SCM job to be run only once in a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827102/can-i-restrict-poll-scm-job-to-be-run-only-once-in-a-day), tells me that I can set the polling to happen only once a day (which is all that we want, in that the coders can check in, up to a certain time).  It does not tell me how to exit out (not to continue with the rest of the build steps), if there are no changes (and, send out a message that there are no changes and thus will be no build tonight).  We are not using pipeline. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the poll scm plugin in by default will not run the job if there are no SCM changes, also you will get GIT polling logs to see the detailed information

Comment: Is this the plugin that you are referring to...https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin ?.   I added it, I see there is the 'Poll SCM' selection under Build Triggers, but I do not see anything else.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/Nxel8GxSk0g.  Is this the plugin?  This will not help, as the job is scheduled to just run at the same time every night, without any user intervention.

Comment: the poll scm trigger is sufficient (the plugin in the first comment), try this behavior in a sample repo with a basic job, it should solve your use case

Comment: I have examined the installed plugin list, and I see that 'Poll SCM Plugin' is listed, yet I see nothing in my test job related to this. Is it possible that you can send a small test config.xml file, or a screen shot of what I should be seeing?  Thanks.